# Group timestamps into days of week and combine data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm creating a table that will function as a heatmap, showing cumulative values (in this case sales) based on the day of week and hour. The y-axis of the table is the days of the week (Sun-Sat) while the x-axis/table header is the hours 0-23.

Where there are multiple days, such as 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-08 are both Mondays, the sales data should combine. Also, after combining these days there may be duplicate hours, in which case the values should combine to show the cumulative value (sales) at that hour on Mondays.

If it matters, this project is in React.

The data will look like this:

```
 data2: [
    {
        day: "2018-01-01",
        sales: [{hour: 6, value: 23}, {hour: 9, value: 164}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-02",
        sales: [{hour: 3, value: 223}, {hour: 4, value: 12}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-03",
        sales: [{hour: 7, value: 323}, {hour: 3, value: 86}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-04",
        sales: [{hour: 5, value: 173}, {hour: 21, value: 65}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-05",
      sales: [{hour: 12, value: 193}, {hour: 1, value: 53}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-06",
      sales: [{hour: 15, value: 263}, {hour: 2, value: 56}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-07",
      sales: [{hour: 18, value: 89}, {hour: 8, value: 378}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-08",
      sales: [{hour: 6, value: 76}, {hour: 17, value: 398}]
    }
  ]
```

I believe I need to create a new array out of this data to make it easier to create the table. So far, at componentDidMount() I'm using moment.js to get the day of week of each date, but I'm not sure how to best combine duplicates and then also duplicates of hours.

I've considered using _underscore but can't figure out how I would use that.

So far:

```
 var newDataArr = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < this.state.data2.length; i++){
    var day = moment(this.state.data2[i].day,'YYY-MM-DD').format('ddd');
    console.log(day);
    if(newDataArr).contains(day) {
       // combine?
    } else { 
       // add new day of week
    }
 }
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
  newData2: [
    {
        day: "Sun",
        sales: [{hour: 6, value: 99}, {hour: 9, value: 164}, {hour: 17, value: 398}]
    },
    {
        day: "Mon",
        sales: [{hour: 3, value: 223}, {hour: 4, value: 12}]
    },
    {
        day: "Tue",
        sales: [{hour: 7, value: 323}, {hour: 3, value: 86}]
    },
    {
        day: "Wed",
        sales: [{hour: 5, value: 173}, {hour: 21, value: 65}]
    },
    {
      day: "Thu",
      sales: [{hour: 12, value: 193}, {hour: 1, value: 53}]
    },
    {
      day: "Fri",
      sales: [{hour: 15, value: 263}, {hour: 2, value: 56}]
    },
    {
      day: "Sat",
      sales: [{hour: 18, value: 89}, {hour: 8, value: 378}]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What is your desired output format?

Comment: I added it to my post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the result in 2 forms. I prefer the 2nd form (Without using the array).

```js
var data = [
    {
        day: "2018-01-01",
        sales: [{hour: 6, value: 23}, {hour: 9, value: 164}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-02",
        sales: [{hour: 3, value: 223}, {hour: 4, value: 12}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-03",
        sales: [{hour: 7, value: 323}, {hour: 3, value: 86}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-04",
        sales: [{hour: 5, value: 173}, {hour: 21, value: 65}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-05",
      sales: [{hour: 12, value: 193}, {hour: 1, value: 53}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-06",
      sales: [{hour: 15, value: 263}, {hour: 2, value: 56}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-07",
      sales: [{hour: 18, value: 89}, {hour: 8, value: 378}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-08",
      sales: [{hour: 6, value: 76}, {hour: 17, value: 398}]
    }
  ];

console.log("Using Method 1 : ");
var result = [];

data.forEach(function(dataobj){
    var day = moment(dataobj.day).format("ddd");
    var detailsindex = result.findIndex(function(elem){ return elem.day==day;});
    var details = detailsindex>-1 ? result[detailsindex] : {day:day,sales:[]};
    dataobj.sales.forEach(function(salesobj){
        var index = details.sales.findIndex(function(elem){return elem.hour==salesobj.hour});
        var obj = index>-1 ? details.sales[index] : {hour:salesobj.hour,value:0};
        obj.value+=salesobj.value;
        if(index>-1) details.sales[index]=obj;
        else details.sales.push(obj)
    });
    if(detailsindex>-1) result[detailsindex]=details;
    else result.push(details)
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

```js
var data = [
    {
        day: "2018-01-01",
        sales: [{hour: 6, value: 23}, {hour: 9, value: 164}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-02",
        sales: [{hour: 3, value: 223}, {hour: 4, value: 12}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-03",
        sales: [{hour: 7, value: 323}, {hour: 3, value: 86}]
    },
    {
        day: "2018-01-04",
        sales: [{hour: 5, value: 173}, {hour: 21, value: 65}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-05",
      sales: [{hour: 12, value: 193}, {hour: 1, value: 53}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-06",
      sales: [{hour: 15, value: 263}, {hour: 2, value: 56}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-07",
      sales: [{hour: 18, value: 89}, {hour: 8, value: 378}]
    },
    {
      day: "2018-01-08",
      sales: [{hour: 6, value: 76}, {hour: 17, value: 398}]
    }
  ];

console.log("Using Method 2 : ");
var result = {};

data.forEach(function(dataobj){
    var day = moment(dataobj.day).format("ddd");
    result[day] = result[day] || {};
    var details = result[day];
    dataobj.sales.forEach(function(salesobj){
        var count = details[salesobj.hour] || 0;
        details[salesobj.hour]=count+salesobj.value;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```